# Is it okay to hard-code complex math logic inside my code?

Tags: c#

Is there a generally accepted best approach to coding complex math? For example:

```
double someNumber = .123 + .456 * Math.Pow(Math.E, .789 * Math.Pow((homeIndex + .22), .012));
```

Is this a point where hard-coding the numbers is okay? Or should each number have a constant associated with it? Or is there even another way, like storing the calculations in config and invoking them somehow?

There will be a lot of code like this, and I'm trying to keep it maintainable.

Note: The example shown above is just one line. There would be tens or hundreds of these lines of code. And not only could the numbers change, but the formula could as well.

Comment: This is far from complex. I thought you meant several thousand lines of code containing nothing but computations.

Comment: Remember `Math.Exp` in place of `Math.Pow(Math.E, ...)`

Comment: When you have to worry about optimizing your math so the executable can be loaded into memory, then you have complex math and should revisit the issue. Otherwise, you'll probably spend more time writing a formula-loading engine. Replacing the constants with variables is probably a good idea.

Comment: _Generally speaking_, if a literal number has significant meaning, you may want to consider storing it in a named variable or constant. For example, if `0.22` was representing a sales tax, you may want to have `const double SalesTax = 0.22;` and use that in your expression. Really, think to yourself if you had to re-read that line 3 months from now, would you understand it and what if someone _other than you_ wrote it? No? Then rewrite it.

Comment: @AustinHenley I agree. I didn't want to paste thousands of lines of code. Like I said, there will be a lot of that. Each line could be much longer and there would be tens or hundreds of those lumped together.

Comment: I disagree with closing this question. This isn't opinion-based, this is about what is considered best practice in our industry. As the accepted answer shows below, there was a good answer for this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Generally, there are two kinds of constants - ones with the meaning to the implementation, and ones with the meaning to the business logic.

It is OK to hard-code the constants of the first kind: they are private to understanding your algorithm. For example, if you are using a [ternary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search) and need to divide the interval in three parts, dividing by a hard-coded `3` is the right approach.

Constants with the meaning outside the code of your program, on the other hand, should not be hard-coded: giving them explicit names gives someone who maintains your code after you leave the company non-zero chances of making correct modifications without having to rewrite things from scratch or e-mailing you for help.

Comment: See, this is exactly what I was hoping for. I'd add that maybe the private numbers should be constants if they'll be used in more than on spot.

Comment: @BobHorn Sometimes, being used in multiple places is not enough for a constant to deserve a name. Even if one implements a binary/ternary search in several places, it does not make sense to define `const int TWO=2;` or `const int THREE=3;" (although I saw this done).

Answer (score 4):

"Is it okay"? Sure. As far as I know, there's no paramilitary police force rounding up those who sin against the one true faith of programming. (Yet.).

Is it wise?

Well, there are all sorts of ways of deciding that - performance, scalability, extensibility, maintainability etc.

On the maintainability scale, this is pure evil. It make extensibility very hard; performance and scalability are probably not a huge concern.

If you left behind a single method with loads of lines similar to the above, your successor would have no chance maintaining the code. He'd be right to recommend a rewrite.

If you broke it down like

```
public float calculateTax(person)
  float taxFreeAmount = calcTaxFreeAmount(person)
  float taxableAmount = calcTaxableAmount(person, taxFreeAmount)
  float taxAmount = calcTaxAmount(person, taxableAmount)
  return taxAmount
end
```

and each of the inner methods is a few lines long, but you left some hardcoded values in there - well, not brilliant, but not terrible.

However, if some of those hardcoded values are likely to change over time (like the tax rate), leaving them as hardcoded values is not okay. It's awful.

The best advice I can give is:

- Spend an afternoon with Resharper, and use its automatic refactoring tools.
- Assume the guy picking this up from you is an axe-wielding maniac who knows where you live.

Answer (score 2):

I usually ask myself whether I can maintain and fix the code at 3 AM being sleep deprived six months after writing the code. It has served me well. Looking at your formula, I'm not sure I can.

Ages ago I worked in the insurance industry. Some of my colleagues were tasked to convert the actuarial formulas into code, first FORTRAN and later C. Mathematical and programming skills varied from colleague to colleague.  What I learned was the following reviewing their code:

- document the actual formula in code; without it, years later you'll have trouble remember the actual formula. External documentation goes missing, become dated or simply may not be accessible.
- break the formula into discrete components that can be documented, reused and tested.
- use constants to document equations; **magic** numbers have very little context and often require existing knowledge for other developers to understand.
- rely on the compiler to optimize code where possible. A good compiler will inline methods, reduce duplication and optimize the code for the particular architecture. In some cases it may duplicate portions of the formula for better performance.

That said, there are times where hard coding just simplify things, especially if those values are well understood within a particular context. For example, dividing (or multiplying) something by 100 or 1000 because you're converting a value to dollars. Another one is to multiply something by 3600 when you'd like to convert hours to seconds. Their meaning is often implied from the greater context.  The following doesn't say much about magic number 100:

```
public static double a(double b, double c)
{
     return (b - c) * 100;
}
```

but the following may give you a better hint:

```
public static double calculateAmountInCents(double amountDue, double amountPaid)
{
     return (amountDue - amountPaid) * 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the above comment states, this is far from complex.

You can however store the *Magic* numbers in constants/app.config values, so as to make it easier for the next developer to maitain your code.

When storing such constants, make sure to explain to the next developer (read yourself in 1 month) what your thoughts were, and what they need to keep in mind.

Also ewxplain what the actual calculation is for and what it is doing.

Comment: If the constants are actually "tunable constants", keep the values in a table, configuration file, etc. so your program does not have to be recompiled. You will likely need sanity checking in you program when you load your tunable constants too.

Answer (score 1):

Do not leave in-line like this.

Constant so you can reuse, easily find, easily change and provides for better maintaining when someone comes looking at your code for the first time.

You can do a config if it can/should be customized. What is the impact of a customer altering the value(s)?  Sometimes it is best to not give them that option.  They could change it on their own then blame you when things don't work.  Then again, maybe they have it in flux more often than your release schedules.

Answer (score 0):

Its worth noting that the C# compiler (or is it the CLR) will automatically inline 1 line methods so if you can extract certain formulas into one liners you can just extract them as methods without any performance loss.

EDIT:

Constants and such more or less depends on the team and the quantity of use. Obviously if you're using the same hard-coded number more than once, constant it. However if you're writing a formula that its likely only you will ever edit (small team) then hard coding the values is fine. It all depends on your teams views on documentation and maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

If the calculation in your line explains something for the next developer then you can leave it, otherwise its better to have calculated constant value in your code or configuration files.

I found one line in production code which was like:

```
int interval = 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

Without any comment, it wasn't hard that the original developer meant `1 hour` in milliseconds, rather than seeing a value of `3600000`.

IMO May be leaving out calculations is better for scenarios like that.

Comment: It might be "easy" or "simple," but that's still a cost that someone has to mentally incur - why not avoid death by 1000 cuts?  Worse is a potential misunderstanding: what if quickly scanning the code someone mis-reads it as 60 seconds?  Mistakes happen. It's so trivial once you have a constants file to add `public const int millisecondsPerHour = 3600000;`; there's no excuse not to do it.  If one developer, one time, got tripped up for 10 minutes because they had to figure out what that line meant, it's worth your time to do it right the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Names can be added for documentation purposes. The amount of documentation needed depends largely on the purpose.

Consider following code:

```
 float e = m * 8.98755179e16;
```

And contrast it with the following one:

```
 const float c = 299792458;
 float e = m * c * c;
```

Even though the variable names are not very 'descriptive' in the latter you'll have much better idea what the code is doing the the first one - arguably there is no need to rename the `c` to `speedOfLight`, `m` to `mass` and `e` to energy as the names are explanatory in their domains.

```
 const float speedOfLight = 299792458;
 float energy = mass * speedOfLight * speedOfLight;
```

I would argue that the second code is the clearest one - especially if programmer can expect to find STR in the code (LHC simulator or something similar). To sum up - you need to find an optimal point. The more verbose code the more context you provide - which might both help to understand the meaning (what is `e` and `c` vs. we do something with mass and speed of light) and obscure the big picture (we square c and multiply by m vs. need of scanning whole line to get equation).

Most constants have some deeper meening and/or established notation so I would consider at least naming it by the convention (`c` for speed of light, `R` for gas constant, `sPerH` for seconds in hour). If notation is not clear the longer names should be used (`sPerH` in class named `Date` or `Time` is probably fine while it is not in `Paginator`). The really obvious constants could be hardcoded (say - division by 2 in calculating new array length in merge sort).